# stretching spinner icon

Tags: android

when I am using my own background theme for spinner it is stretching icon.

[image]

my spinner code is:

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinnerCategory" style="@style/spinner"
                    android:entries="@array/category_array" android:prompt="@string/category_prompt"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner" />
```

my spinner.xml is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_normal" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_selected" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_normal" />

</selector>
```

and images I copied from the sdk 4.

How can I stop spinner icon stretching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I just hard-coded the height of spinner to somewhere near about 48-50 dip.

Comment: i want layout_width=100dip that is my requirement how can i do it?

Comment: put android:layout_width="100dip" attribute in your xml code for spinner.

Comment: ok i have solve the problem by changing height 36dip to  25 dip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 9 patch image like in this tuto: http://stephenpengilley.blogspot.fr/2013/01/android-custom-spinner-tutorial.html

or create a dynamic drawable background (dropdown_shape.xml) like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:bottom="6sp"
            android:top="6sp"
            >
            <shape
                android:thickness="0dp"
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
                <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#000000" />
                <corners android:radius="6sp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:right="18sp"
            >
            <vector
                android:height="12sp"
                android:width="16sp"
                android:viewportHeight="100"
                android:viewportWidth="100" >
                <group>
                    <path
                        android:strokeWidth="3"
                        android:strokeColor="#000000"
                        android:fillColor="#FF0000"
                        android:pathData="m 0,0 l 100,0 -50,100 z" />
                </group>
            </vector>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

and use it like:

```
<Spinner
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="58dp"
     android:entries="@array/month_array"
     android:background="@drawable/dropdown_shape"
     android:paddingStart="12dp"
     android:paddingEnd="40dp"
     android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```